# Udev event loop after 21.04

Tags: udev, 21.04

a few years ago, I wrote a small utility application for MSI gaming notebooks to control the integrated keyboard's backlight. It is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/Gibtnix/MSIKLM).

Recently, some problems began which are presumably caused by the behavior of udev. Since the keyboard backlight resets after each reboot, I also added a script that creates a udev rule to trigger the program after each reboot. This worked fine so far. However, now the udev rule seems to be triggered over and over again as discussed and tested in the respective GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Gibtnix/MSIKLM/issues/39).

Does anybody know how this can be fixed? I suspect it is an relatively easy fix, still I do not know what has to be adjusted in the udev rules.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update: With the recent kernel updates, the problem seems to be solved.